# The constuctability of n-gon(regular n-polygon)

Tags: galois-theory, polygons, galois-extensions, cyclotomic-fields, fermat-numbers

The problem is as follows.

> Let $p$ is odd prime and suppose that a regular $p$-gon is constructible. Then show that $p$ is a Fermat prime.

I solved the $$\Bigg[\Bbb Q\left(\cos\frac{2\pi}{p}\right):\Bbb Q\Bigg]= \frac{p-1}{2}$$ and $$x^{2k+1} +1$$ is divisible by $x+1$ by using $p$th cyclotomic extension. And by the remark
If $a$ is constructible number, $a$ is algebraic nubmer and $$[Q(a):Q]=2^r$$
 for some $a \in N :$ national numbers

So i have the statement $$p=2^{r+1}+1.$$

But, i have to show $p$ is a Fermat prime. Then, how can i solve problem with my result above?

Please, help.
(Better than recommendation for similar question, i want it to solve this condition.)

Comment: This is a good start. Show that if $2^n+1$ is a prime, then $n$ is a power of two. This has been done on our site many times already.

Comment: Ummm,,, what is n that you say in my statement? I'm sorry, please link the site in this problem. I just saw the p^k- region , generally, or the converse.

Comment: My $n$ is your $r+1$.

Comment: [For example](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/491830/11619). [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/) often helps, but isn't ideal. This is a FAQ.